# Не влезает логотип сайта, если не войти в аккаунт

Tags: дефект, дизайн, приватный-режим

1. > [image: Не влезает логотип сайта на странице профиля участника на основном сайте, если не войти в аккаунт]
2. > [image: Не влезает логотип сайта на странице профиля участника на Мете, если не войти в аккаунт]

Так не на всех страницах. Как минимум, при просмотре профилей участников. Возможно, ещё где-то.

Браузер Google Chrome 81, в Firefox так же.